# Фильтрация вывода товара из заказа

Tags: django, django-admin, django-orm, django-filter, django-model

Нужно сделать фильтрацию вывода товара из заказа.
Есть заказ и нужно вывести только те товары, у которых категория, например, "Смартфоны"...
Как можно это сделать?

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255, verbose_name='Наименование')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name='Категория', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/%Y/%m/%d/', verbose_name='Изображение', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Описание', null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Цена')


class Order(models.Model):
   #Информация о заказчике
   #Информация о заказе


class OrderProduct(models.Model):
   orders = models.ForeignKey('Order', verbose_name='Заказ', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='related_orders_product')
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product, verbose_name='Категория', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   #Остальные данные типа количество и общая цена
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
order_smartphones = OrderProduct.objects.filter(product__category=smartphones_category_id)
```

вместо `smartphones_category_id` нужно подставить id категории "Смартфоны", либо саму категорию

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships